# Use a PATCH request to update a JSON file with Express

Tags: node.js, json, express

I have two files: `stocks.json` and `index.js`. I want to be able to PATCH entries in `stocks.json` (for example, to update a `Price` of an existing company).

`stocks.json` (sample):

```
  [{
    "symbol": "AMZN",
    "company": "Amazon",
    "price": 1450.5
  },
  {
    "symbol": "SHOP",
    "company": "Shopify",
    "price": 1150.5
  }]
```

The `index.js` uses fs and express to make requests to and from the `stocks.json` file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())

const stocks = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/stocks.json`))

app.patch("/stock/:id", (req, res) => {
    console.dir(req.path);
    console.log(req.body);

    const id = req.params.id;
    const stock = stocks.find(el => el.symbol === id)
    if (!stock) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            status: "fail",
            message: "invalid ID"
        })
    }

    stock.price = req.body.price;
    fs.writeFile(`${__dirname}/stocks.json`, JSON.stringify(stock, 0, 4), err => {
        res.status(201).json({
            status: 'success',
            data: {
                data: stock
            }
        })
    })
});
```

I can POST a new company to the file, but I am having trouble PATCHING an existing entry. If I send a PATCH request to `/stock/SHOP` with the body `{ "price": 900 }`,  The PATCH logic simply overwrites the existing stocks.json file (deleting existing entries).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the proper protocol here but I found a solution that works for me.

Find the index of the entry you want in the array of stocks, then update the price there. Then you can re-write all stocks to file.
    entryIndex = stocks.indexOf(stock);
    stocks[entryIndex].price = req.body.price;
    fs.writeFile(`${__dirname}/stocks.json`, JSON.stringify(stocks, 0, 4), err => {
        res.status(201).json({
            status: 'success',
            data: {
                data: stocks
            }
        })
    })

Comment: `PATCH` alone will not update your JSON object as expected. In your code, you are setting `stock.price = req.body.price`. This actually overwrites the last saved value. Instead, if you want to keep historical values, consider making the field `stock.prices` with type Array. Then, latest price will be `stock.prices[stock.prices.length-1]`. New prices can be added like this: `stock.prices.push(req.body.price)`. Hope that helps.